# Make str_replace not replace a letter if follows another letter

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string which contains a math formula, like `T + ST + s + t` ...

I'm replacing all those letter identifiers with numbers using:

```
$ids = array(
    'T'    => $t1,
    'ST',  => $st,
    's',   => $s1,
    't',   => $t2,
    'N',   => 1,     
);

foreach ($ids as $id => $value) {
    if (strpos($formula, $id) !== false) {
        $formula = str_replace($id, $value, $formula);
    }
}
```

Which is ok in certain situations.
But if the formula has ST at the beginning I get a string like `S345324` ..

I fixed this by moving ST in the first position in my array, but I feel it's not really the best option :)

Are there any other "nicer" solutions?

Comment: ok nvm, found out why, I'm so silly :)

Comment: Could you add some example inputs and output to your post?

Comment: Could you post what was wrong and how you fixed it for future Googlers?  Although this is probably a one off, there's nothing more frustrating than having a similar problem, searching for it and coming across someone who appears to have had the same problem and not posted a follow up.

Comment: This question is useless, maybe you could place a request for deletion?

Comment: It was replacing the first T in ST with a number, so the string would become like S455

Comment: ok, I re-written my question, because I still have some problems with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)?

```
$ids = array(
  'T'    => $t1,
  'ST'   => $st,
  's'    => $s1,
  't'    => $t2,
  'N'    => 1,     
);

$formula = strtr($formula, $ids);
```

Note that since `strtr()` always tries to find the longest possible match, it won't replace occurrences of `ST` with `S$t1` (instead of `$st`), regardless of how your `$replace_pairs` array is ordered.

---

Example [**(as seen on codepad)**](http://codepad.org/ljlhcync):

```
$ids = array(
  'T'    => 10,
  'ST'   => 20,
  's'    => 30,
  't'    => 40,
  'N'    => 1,     
);

$formula = 'T + ST + s + t';
echo strtr($formula, $ids);
```

Prints:

```
10 + 20 + 30 + 40
```